# Use more than 100 multi-domains with single ssl cerficate

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, https

I have a requirement of providing different domain to each seller in my e-commerce application like Shopify does. I don't think using multiple ssl certificates(one ssl certificate for each domain/seller) is a good option. For managing multiple domains, as I get to know so far is that I can use SAN multi-domain certificates which can handle different domains but only upto 100 different domains. Is it possible to handle multiple SAN ssl certificates on single server? Also I am using load-balancer for my AWS instances, how can I manage my load-balancer in case of multiple SAN ssl certificates. Can any one please answer?

Answer (score 1):

Currently most certificate authorities limit the maximum number of SANs you can request in a single certificate to around 100, although, I've heard of some offering up to 150.

You can use multiple SSL certificates in Apache with multiple `VirtualHost` blocks, and Nginx with multiple `server` blocks. You can also specify multiple certificates for the same `VirtualHost` or `server` block, if you didn't want to split them up. Or if each client is getting their own block anyway, you can just point them all to the same certificate that has their domain in the SAN field. It just depends on your setup.

Whichever method you choose, you'll want to ensure that the `VirtualHost` or `server` block has a `ServerName` (apache) or `server_name` (nginx) listed for each SAN it will be answering for.

As for load balancing with multiple certificates in AWS, Amazon [implemented support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/elastic-load-balancing-application-load-balancers-now-support-multiple-ssl-certificates-and-smart-certificate-selection-using-server-name-indication-sni/) for this recently (October 2017).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know whether cPanel has an option for this? Cheers

Comment: The cPanel [documentation](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/security/guide-to-ssl/#domain-and-rate-limits) states a limit of 1000 domains when using the AutoSSL feature. Although, if you need that many, you might consider breaking them up with multiple certificates and virtual hosts.